# Automatically show Form widget below textfield upon entering certain number of characters if data not found in firestore

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I want to create a flutter web app page (& android tablet app) where have a form with text fields. When user starts typing in a field it would fetch previous documents(products) from firestore collection 'product' and show them below it in a List. On taping or pressing enter by keyboard it should select the item from list. If user types a new product name, say as soon as first 8 characters have been typed, a sub-form with new text field appears to enter product details.

My Questions, current code and problems are as below:

1. When selecting a previous product in ProductDropDown widget, OnTap inside a Stack widget does not work, but on Mouse click it works. Tried AutoComplete here, but navigating autocomplete options by arrow keys and pressing enter does not register my value in firestore database.
2. What Flutter widgets can be used to autoshows below textfield as soon as certain number of characters are typed. I used showModalBottomSheet on a click of button but I want to fill new new product asap because fields down in the form depends on its values
3. Best way to use FutureBuilder so that firebase costs are minimised - I read about Provider (FutureProvider), did not get anything for it related to firebase costs
4. There is another field in the form like product which fetch data from another collection

Some hints or references & concepts will be helpful in this case as I'm new to app development.

```
// In a stateful widget

  late Future<List<Product>> productList;
  List<Product> _tempProducts = [];
  TextEditingController? productController;

  Future<List<Product>> fetchProductsFromBase() async {
    List<Product> _productList = [];

    var productDataSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product').get();
    for (var client in productDataSnapshot.docs) {
      _productList.add(Product.fromMap(client.data()));
    }
    _tempProducts = _productList; // Storing in temporary list to filter them using a function
    return _productList;
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    productList = fetchProductsFromBase();
    productController = TextEditingController();
  }

bool showProductDropDown = false;
Widget productDropDown() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: productList,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Product>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.length > 0) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              LimitedBox(
                maxHeight: 292.0,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 2.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: colorJotGreen.shade50, width: 1.5)),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: _tempProducts.length > 0
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: _tempProducts.length,
                            // CreateJobDropListItem() is a StatefulWidget -> Container wrapped in a Inkwell
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) => CreateJobDropListItem(
                                  key: ValueKey(_tempProducts[index].pid),
                                  text: _tempProducts[index].pid,
                                  trailingText:
                                      '${_tempProducts[index].dim_x.toString()} by ${_tempProducts[index].dim_y.toString()}',
                                  TapCallBack: () {
                                    productController!.text = _tempProducts[index].pid;
                                  },
                                ))
                        : Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'No matches found',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelSmall,
                            )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && !snapshot.hasData) {
          return LimitedBox(
            maxHeight: 292.0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Text(
                'No previous entries for any product',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelSmall,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else
          return LimitedBox(
            maxHeight: 292.0,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
      },
    );
  }

  void _runProductFilter([String searchKeyword = '']) {
    List<Product> results = [];
    // do something - this functions works fine so compacting code here
    setState(() {
      _tempProducts = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
         // Lots of UI - SafeArea -> Scaffold -> SingleChildScrollView -> Form -> Columns & Rows -> then 
            Column(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: productController,
                              validator: (pid) {
                                if (pid!.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Enter Product ID';
                                } else
                                  return null;
                              },
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  showProductDropDown = !showProductDropDown;
                                  if (showClientDropDown == true) {
                                    showClientDropDown = false;
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                              onTapOutside: (_) {
                                setState(() {
                                  showProductDropDown = false;
                                });
                              },
                              onChanged: (String value) {
                                if (showProductDropDown == false) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    showProductDropDown = true;
                                  });
                                }
                                _runProductFilter(value);
                              },
                            ),
                            showProductDropDown ? productDropDown() : Container()
                          ],
                        )

  }
  
 // Want to replace below widget with something that shows below the text field as soon a user types (8 characters) a new product not already in database 
 Future<void> addNewProduct(
      BuildContext context, String clientUID, jeUser clientDetails, String pid) async {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
     // Another Stateful Widget class with Form & try on catch error to store data
    );
}
```